# What could cause NetworkX & PyGraphViz to work fine alone but not together?

Tags: python, graph, graphviz, networkx, pygraphviz

I'm working to learning some Python graph visualization. I found a few blog posts doing [some](https://kenmxu.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/network-x-4-8-2/) [things](http://www.randomhacks.net/2009/12/29/visualizing-wordnet-relationships-as-graphs/) I wanted to try. Unfortunately I didn't get too far, encountering this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'`

The simplest snip of code which **reproduces the error** on my system is this,

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx
In [2]: G=nx.complete_graph(5)
In [3]: nx.draw_graphviz(G)
------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
&lt;ipython-input-3-481ad1c1771c&gt; in &lt;module&gt;()
----&gt; 1 nx.draw_graphviz(G)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.pyc in draw_graphviz(G, prog, **kwargs)
982 See networkx.draw_networkx() for a description of optional keywords.
983 """
--&gt; 984 pos = nx.drawing.graphviz_layout(G, prog)
985 draw(G, pos, **kwargs)
986
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'
```

I found a similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859001/how-do-you-get-networkx-graphviz-layout-to-work), and [posts](http://www.jhreview.com/tech-stack/questions/22698227/python-installation-issues-with-pygraphviz-and-graphviz) having difficulty with this combo, but not quite the same error. One was [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587445/drawing-graph-in-graphviz-layout-in-python-using-nx-draw-graphviz-gives-error), but it automagically resolved itself.

**First, I verified all the required packages** for [NetworkX](https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/install.html#requirements) and PyGraphViz (which lists similar requirements to [Scipy](http://scipy.org/install.html#individual-binary-and-source-packages)) were installed.

**Next, I looked for snips to test my installation of these modules in Python.** The first two examples are from the [NetworkX Reference Documentation](https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_agraph). This lists a few example snips using both MatPlotLib and GraphViz.

**The MatPlotLib code example works for me (renders an image to the screen)**,

```
In [11]: import networkx as nx
In [12]: G=nx.complete_graph(5)
In [13]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [13]: nx.draw(G)
In [13]: plt.show()
```

However, the **GraphViz snips also produce similar errors,**

```
In [16]: import networkx as nx
In [17]: G=nx.complete_graph(5)
In [18]: H=nx.from_agraph(A)
------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-808fa68cefaa> in <module>()
----> 1 H=nx.from_agraph(A)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_agraph'
In [19]: A=nx.to_agraph(G)
------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-32d1616bb41a> in <module>()
----> 1 A=nx.to_agraph(G)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_agraph'
In [20]: print G
complete_graph(5)
```

**Then I tried PyGraphViz's tutorial page** on [Layout & Drawing](http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/development/tutorial.html#layout-and-drawing). This has some snips as well. **PyGraphViz passed** with Neato (default), PyDot, and Circo Post Script output (viewed using Gimp). (The only difference is these PyGraphViz examples are not rendered to the display, but to files).

```
In [1]: import pygraphviz as pgv
In [2]: d={'1': {'2': None}, '2': {'1': None, '3': None}, '3': {'2': None}}
In [3]: A=pgv.AGraph(d)
In [4]: A.write("pygraphviz_test_01.dot")
In [5]: A.layout()
In [6]: A.draw('pygraphviz_test_01.png')
```

**Adding to the complexity,** PyGraphViz [requires GraphViz](http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.3rc1/install.html#requirements) package binaries in order to work. I'm using Arch Linux, and installed that distro's version. Arch Linux has an [example to test installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Graphviz) (again, output to file) **which also passed**.

What am I missing? **What could cause NetworkX & PyGraphViz to work fine alone but not together?**

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is a small bug in the `draw_graphviz` function in networkx-1.11 triggered by the change that the graphviz drawing tools are no longer imported into the top level namespace of networkx.

The following is a workaround

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.complete_graph(5)

In [3]: from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

In [4]: pos = graphviz_layout(G)

In [5]: nx.draw(G, pos)
```

To use the other functions such as `to_agraph`, `write_dot`, etc you will need to explicitly use the longer path name

```
 nx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot()
```

or import the function into the top-level namespace

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot()
write_dot()
```

These command use `graphviz` to calculate the positioning of the nodes (`graphviz_layout` [uses](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html?highlight=graphviz_layout#networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout) `neato` per default), and `matplotlib` to actually [plot (i.e. draw)](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) the graph.

Answer (score 3):

`nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout()` seems to be the way to use `graphviz_layout` in *Networkx release 1.11*.

You may need to install [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) via

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

Some example code from the documentation:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.complete_graph(4)
pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G)
```

I suggest this as the [Graphviz_layout documentation for 1.11](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout.html?highlight=graphviz_layout)

Comment: How do you run graphviz binary?