# "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int" when using graphviz dot layout

Tags: python, networkx, pygraphviz

I'm trying to use pygraphviz' dot layout with networkX. But I get the error

```
 File "C:\Users\msi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1028, in preParse
    while loc < instrlen and instring[loc] in wt:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Could it be that graphviz does not work with python 3. which I'm using?

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.DiGraph()

n = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
e = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,6),(3,7),
     (8,9),(8,10),(9,11),(9,12),(10,13),(10,14),(7,8)]

G.add_nodes_from(n)
G.add_edges_from(e)

pos=nx.graphviz_layout(G,prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I believe here is the solution to this problem: [What could cause NetworkX & PyGraphViz to work fine alone but not together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279733/what-could-cause-networkx-pygraphviz-to-work-fine-alone-but-not-together) Anyway, when I applied suggested change to your code, it ran correctly without errors.

Comment: Yes I followed the advice I found there and on other sources and posts. The problem is, I can't even install pygraphviz. I have profoundly looked into the issue but I can't seem to solve it. I ended up writing a positioning algorithm for networkx, that fulfills my needs. Thanks for the answer nonetheless.